# Multiple HTTPS entry points with ACME LetsEncrypt DNS in Traefik

Tags: traefik

I have successfully configured ACME / LetsEncrypt to use DNS challenge, but I'm still unable to create multiple HTTPS / TLS entry points on different ports (443 and 8443) using guidance from [this post](https://github.com/containous/traefik/issues/2339#issuecomment-340022653).

> Error creating TLS config: No certificates found for TLS entrypoint
>   https8443

Here is the relevant section of my config:

```
defaultEntryPoints = ["http", "https443"]

[entryPoints]

  [entryPoints.http]
  address = ":80"
    [entryPoints.http.redirect]
    entryPoint = "https443"

  [entryPoints.https443]
  address = ":443"
    [entryPoints.https443.tls]

  [entryPoints.https8443]
  address = ":8443"
    [entryPoints.https8443.tls]

[acme]
email = "user@example.com"
storage = "/path/to/acme.json"
onHostRule = true
dnsProvider = "cloudflare"
#delayDontCheckDNS = 0
entryPoint = "https443"

[[acme.domains]]
  main = "example.com"
  sans = ["a.example.com", "b.example.com"]
```

Answer (score 4):

After analyzing deeper the behavior of ACME into Træfik, it seems to be impossible, for the moment, to share an ACME certificate between differents entryPoints.

Indeed, ACME certificates will be linked to the entryPoint given in the configuration.